# How can we delete a node in doubly linkedlist based on value passed, which can be any of node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently, I am a beginner in JavaScript and node js, I am working on Linked list where I have to read a sentence from a file and split it into words and add words in the Linked list. I have to input a word if it is present it should delete it and if not present it should add it. 
Here I want to delete a node based on value, I am able to delete a node which is referenced by head and tail. Basically, I have to create a generic function where I can pass list and value which I have to delete and return list so I can write it into a file.

I had followed [this](https://hackernoon.com/the-little-guide-of-linked-list-in-javascript-9daf89b63b54) link to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to find the node, which with a linked list requires a linear scan. Then you delete the node by updating the references in the previous and next node to point to each other instead of the node being deleted.

```
found.prev.next = found.next
found.next.prev = found.prev
```

If you didn't find the word, just add it to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Double linked list in javascript 

function Node(value) {
    this.data = value;
    this.previous = null;
    this.next = null;
}

function DoublyList() {
    this._length = 0;
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
}

//You can add nodes using 
DoublyList.prototype.add = function(value) {
    var node = new Node(value); 
    ........ and so on
}

//search function can be like
DoublyList.prototype.search = function(value){
  var currentNode = this.head;
  while (currentNode.data != value) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
   }
  return currentNode
}
```